# Best way to design for one-to-many code values in Oracle

Tags: oracle, performance, database-design, oracle11g, database-partitioning

We receive several millions of records per day on temperature metrics. Most of the pertinent metadata for these records is maintained in a single partitioned table by date (month).  We are going to start receiving up to 20 individual codes associated with this data. The intent is to ultimately allow searching by these codes.

What would be the most effective way to store this data to minimize search response time?  The database is Oracle 11gR2.

Some options I was taking into consideration:

(1) Create a separate table with main record id and code values.  Something like

```
id        code
--        ----
 1        AA
 1        BB
 1        CC
 2        AA
 2        CC
 2        DD
```

Concerns:

- would probably require a bitmap index on the code column, but the table is highly transactional so no bitmap
- table would get huge over time with up to 20 codes per main record

(2) Create a separate table partitioned by code values.

Concerns:

- partition maintenance for new codes
- search performance

(3) Add a XMLType column to existing table and format the codes for each record into XML and create an XMLIndex on the column:  Something like:

```
<C1>AA</C1>
<C2>BB</C2>
<C3>CC</C3>
```

Concerns:

- query response time when searching on CODE probably would be poor

Any recommendations are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Create a separate table with main record id and code values.  The index on code will perform well enough for queries and not slow down inserts too much.  I'm assuming there will be no updates or deletes on this separate table.

Comment: Do you mean that in the future you would like to query a table to find all IDs that have a code A, or something different? At up to 20m records a day the amount of data is going to get incomprehensible pretty fast.

Answer (score 2):

You need to benchmark different approaches.  There's no way we can give you meaningful solutions without knowing much more about your scenario.  How many different codes will there be in total?  What's the average number of codes per reading?  Will there be a noticeable skew in the distribution of codes?  What access paths do you need to support for searching by `code`?

Then there's the matter of how you load data (batches?  drip feed?).  And what benefits you derive from using partitioning.

Anyway.  Here's one more approach, which is an amalgamation of your (1) and (2).

Given that your main table is partitioned by month you should probably partition any child table with the same scheme.  You can subpartition by `code` as well.

```
create table main_codes
    ( reading_dt date not null
      , main_id number not null
      , code varchar2(2)
      , constraint main_codes_pk primary key (code, reading_dt, main_id) using index local
     )
partition by range (reading_dt) 
subpartition by list (code) 
subpartition template 
( 
    subpartition sp_aa values ( 'AA' ), 
    subpartition sp_bb values ( 'BB' ), 
    subpartition sp_cc values ( 'CC' ), 
    subpartition sp_dd values ( 'DD' )
) 
(
    partition p_2015JAN values less than (date '2015-02-01' ),
    partition p_2015FEB values less than (date '2015-03-01' ),
    partition p_2015MAR values less than (date '2015-04-01' )
)
/
```

You'll probably want a foreign on the main table too:

```
alter table main_codes 
    add constraint code_main_fk foreign key (reading_dt, main_id)
    references main_table (reading_dt, main_id)
/

create index code_main_idx on  main_codes (entry_dt, id) local
/
```

Depending on the number of codes you have, creating the subpartition template could be tedious.  This is why Nature gave us cut'n'paste.

But whatever you do, *don't go down the XML path*.

Comment: APC, thanks so much for the detailed response.

There will be 20 or so different codes in total, with the potential to add more in the future. The codes should be evenly distributed (ie. no skew).  The data will come in on a drip feed with roughly 20 codes for each 2-3 million records loaded per day, therefore 40-60 million codes per day.

We will need to provide the ability to search by code itself or search on date & code.

With codes of this nature, bitmap would obviously be the ideal solution, but with the highly transactional nature of this table that's not possible.

Comment: (cont).I was considering the composite partition (by date then by code), but if a user were to search by ONLY code, this would scan all the partitions. Of course, this would work nicely for the date & code searches. Unfortunately, this seems to be the catch-22 with either partitioning alternative. 

I was hoping that I could come up with a solution that would seamlessly accommodate any new codes in the future without manual intervention and/or downtime (ie. partition maintenance).

Thanks again for your insight.

BTW, thanks APC for nicely formatting my original post.